Is it possible to implement react lazy loading based on routes with a single spa architecture?
I'm currently building a single spa react application that is being "consumed" by an orquestrator, this project is a simple, normal, project that uses react and has 4 routes, all of them is being wrapped by a React.Suspense component and being imported using React.lazy. This should work fine but when I first enter a page, it downloads the bundle code just fine, but the page doesn't load, it keeps running the Suspense fallback, and if I exit the page and come back (not reloading the page just accessing a different route, the page loads fine.
Here is some of my config files that I hope it helps:
My babel.config.json:
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        "runtime": "automatic"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "useESModules": true,
        "regenerator": false
      },
      "babel-loader"
    ]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            "targets": "current node"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}

My webpack.config.js:
const path = require('path');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const singleSpaDefaults = require('webpack-config-single-spa-react-ts');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  const dotEnvFile = {
    production: '.env',
  };
  const defaultConfig = singleSpaDefaults({
    orgName: 'org-name',
    projectName: 'project-name',
    orgPackagesAsExternal: false,
    webpackConfigEnv: env,
    argv,
  });

  return merge(defaultConfig, {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      },
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
        },
      ],
    },

    plugins: [
      new Dotenv({
        path: dotEnvFile.production,
      }),
      new ESLintPlugin({
        extensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
        fix: false,
        emitError: true,
        emitWarning: true,
        failOnError: false,
      }),
    ],
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
  });
};

I tried several different approaches that consists in changing the webpack.config.js, mainly adding adding things like:
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
  },

This resulted in a issue where my project itself would result in a 404 when loading, probably because now the orquestrator is not finding the project by its "normal" name. adding "project-name" only to filename in the output object fixes this issue, but then I get a different error that's:
[webpack-dev-middleware] Error: Conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename "org-name-project-name.js" (chunks main and vendors). After several attempts to resolve this matter, I get the following: application '@org-name/project-name' died in status LOADING_SOURCE_CODE: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__esModule'). And again, I have no idea if I have to do all of this for the React.Suspense error or if it's something completely different.
